# How should we revise the tags for the different Exalted editions?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

With Exalted currently in the 3rd edition (since this year), we should make sure that those 2nd/2.5th Edition Questions are marked distinct from those that target 3rd Edition specifically.

At the moment, I know of 1 question about 3rd Edition specifically:

- [Artifact & Evocation creation guidelines?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/90497/artifact-evocation-creation-guidelines)

On the other hand, questions about 2/2.5 are numerous (no reason mentioned means, it is specified to target 2/2.5 in the question). At times, those questions can not be pinned to either variant specifically:

- [Exalted Land Speed Record Build](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/7606/exalted-land-speed-record-build) (references Dreams of first Age, a 2nd Ed Book)
- [Sixth Excellency and Craft abilities- Is this as awesome as I think it is?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/56703/sixth-excellency-and-craft-abilities-is-this-as-awesome-as-i-think-it-is) (judging by date)
- [Can the Infallible Messenger find an Alchemical Exalt?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/58474/can-the-infallible-messenger-find-an-alchemical-exalt)
- [Specialties and weapon types](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/41596/specialties-and-weapon-types) (references page in Main Book = 2nd Edition Core)
- [Can a player with "Harmonious Academic Methodology" train himself without spending XP?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/28861/can-a-player-with-harmonious-academic-methodology-train-himself-without-spendi) (2nd ed charm in question)
- [What would this Sorcery Fix do for Exalted?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/27335/what-would-this-sorcery-fix-do-for-exalted) (presumably 2nd ed by date)
- [What does it take for a new dragonblood character to know sorcery?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/21768/what-does-it-take-for-a-new-dragonblood-character-to-know-sorcery) (specific about a 2nd ed book)
- [How deadly are extras in Exalted 2nd ed.?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/16264/how-deadly-are-extras-in-exalted-2nd-ed)
- [How do I make a physical challenge for Dawn-caste Solar Exalted?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/15046/how-do-i-make-a-physical-challenge-for-dawn-caste-solar-exalted)
- [What is a challenge to a Perfect character?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/19066/what-is-a-challenge-to-a-perfect-character) (judging by date)
- [What systems use an initiative system similar to Exalted 2nd Edition?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/11508/what-systems-use-an-initiative-system-similar-to-exalted-2nd-edition)
- [Sorcery and Occult Excellencies](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/10923/sorcery-and-occult-excellencies)
- [Are any solar medicine charms effective against Final Viridescence?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72181/are-any-solar-medicine-charms-effective-against-final-viridescence)
- [Are Fair Folk charms supposed to cost 12xp for Eclipse caste?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69452/are-fair-folk-charms-supposed-to-cost-12xp-for-eclipse-caste) (judging by date & XP cost scales mentioned)
- [What is the difference between being inside or outside of fate from a mechanical point of view?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/65668/what-is-the-difference-between-being-inside-or-outside-of-fate-from-a-mechanical) (question about mechanics, most likely 2nd Edition, because it was before the release of 3rd)
- [Exalted -- stacking multiple types of armor](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/10738/exalted-stacking-multiple-types-of-armor)
- [Exalted - Sidereal Dice Cap](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/10302/exalted-sidereal-dice-cap)
- [Bonus dice and flurries](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/10130/bonus-dice-and-flurries)
- [Exalted Limit Breaks - How do I get them to occur more often?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/7469/exalted-limit-breaks-how-do-i-get-them-to-occur-more-often) (Virtues are mentioned, so most likely 2E)
- [What is Exalted Paranoia Combat?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/10602/what-is-exalted-paranoia-combat) (Judging by date and reference to the Forum, which was the White Wolf Forum back then, now defunct).
- [Does No-Key the Mushroom King appear in any Exalted 2nd Ed Sourcebooks?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/7080/does-no-key-the-mushroom-king-appear-in-any-exalted-2nd-ed-sourcebooks)

There is even one, that asks about tirst edition!

- [Alternate Locust Crusades](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/10613/alternate-locust-crusades)

Contested/unclear in edition is sometimes a case too:

- [Do Alchemical Exalts need Slots to learn Martial Arts?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/58669/do-alchemical-exalts-need-slots-to-learn-martial-arts) (1E or 2E? more likely 2E)
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77762/can-you-cause-harm-through-crush-while-clinching (March 2016 - could be based on 2.5, the leak of development/playtest materil of 3E or proper 3E
- [Rules modifications for Exalted Clinches](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/7321/rules-modifications-for-exalted-clinches) (no clear ref to 1E or 2E, probably 2E)
- [How can a beginner GM deal with multitude of charms in Exalted?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/929/how-can-a-beginner-gm-deal-with-multitude-of-charms-in-exalted) (might refer to 1E or 2E, most likely later)

---

So, my proposition is:

- [exalted](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exalted)  for all of the background or version agnostic needs
- for the rule-specific ones:

  - [exalted-1](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exalted-1), [exalted-2](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exalted-2)  and [exalted-3](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exalted-3), depending on edition. This would pick up the scheme of calling it "E1" etc, omitting the edition.
  - OR: [exalted-1e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exalted-1e), [exalted-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exalted-2e)  and [exalted-3e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exalted-3e), to better to follow the tagging scheme on the site:
  - Should the need for a distinct [exalted-2.5](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exalted-2.5) or [exalted-2.5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exalted-2.5e) be there, it should be implemented, but tagging it as exalted 2.5 would have to imply tagging also exalted 2, because the difference between 2 and 2.5 is mainly made by just applying the huge errata document or ignoring it.

Comment: Every other game tag where the releases are called *editions* (second edition, third edition, etc) uses the "e" shorthand: [tag:dark-heresy-2e], [tag:gurps-4e], [tag:dnd-5e], [tag:7th-sea-2e], etc. Since Exalted's second and third versions are called "second edition" and "third edition", conventionally we'd tag Exalted as [exalted-1e] [exalted-2e] and [exalted-3e], not simply [exalted-1] etc.

Comment: oops! Though the forums I am on usually refer to them as E1, E2, E2.5 and E3

Comment: Just a note regarding the recent retagging: mods have a tool to rename tags without editing posts, so when a simple tag rename needs to be done and it's on more than a few posts, you can just ask us to do it instead and it will save the front page from the minor edits.

Comment: @SSD: true, true...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fibericon mentioned [in RPG chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11?m=33577628#33577628) that "The editions are very different, and somewhat polarizing among players." He described himself as being "pretty firmly in the 2.5e camp", which suggests to me that even 2.5e is different from 2e. (If that's inaccurate, dear reader, I suggest you leave an alternative answer! I'm not an Exalted player myself, I'm going by second-hand information.)

With that in mind and our tagging convention for games with editions, I suggest the tags would be:

- [exalted](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exalted) for the series, if we need it
- [exalted-1e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exalted-1e)
- [exalted-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exalted-2e) and [exalted-2.5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exalted-2.5e) separately
- [exalted-3e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exalted-3e)

I can't tell you which questions are 2e or 2.5e though.

Comment: 2.5 is kind of the result if you apply the 300 page errata or not...

Comment: I hope that if a 2.5e tag is not appropriate, answers will arrive to suggest some contrary action. (I am also hoping that answering at all will prompt more responses to this question from Exalted players on the site.)

Comment: Sidenote: finally updated to 2e/3e convention